# wmctrl on Ubuntu Touch

Tags: wmctrl

I want to control windows via Window manager controls (wmctrl).

I am able to successfully switch between qml application windows using wmctrl commands on the Ubuntu Desktop.

But I am running same applications on Ubuntu Touch Nexus tablet. It results in an error as shown

"Cannot open display".

Does Ubuntu Touch supports the window management? How to achieve this?

Comment: Anyone has info on this?

Answer (score 1):

wmctrl is a UNIX/Linux command line tool to interact with an EWMH/NetWM compatible X Window Manager.

Ubuntu Desktop still uses compiz as its compositing window manager, which talks to X server. so wmctl is applicable.

while Ubuntu Touch is moving towards a new graphics infrastructure based on [mir](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Mir/Spec), which is a replacement for X server. So there's no X11 stuff on Ubuntu Touch, no DISPLAY environment variable.

wmctl expects the X11 DISPLAY environment variable and it complains "Cannot open display" when it's not there.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Reading on Mir, I found something called Shell which provides application window management. But I could not find much info on API or commands available. Is Mir available ?

Comment: [Unity8](https://launchpad.net/unity8) is going to be the 'Shell'. it's currently only available on Ubuntu Touch. Ubuntu's Mir convergence won't happen before Ubuntu 14.10.